# Rewrite cryptopython code to golang crypto

Tags: python, go

I want to decode string in golang, but i dont know how to do it in golang. I have python code.
encryptedNonce(in both cases) is encrypted string which i need to decode with private key.

```
nonceHash = hashlib.sha256()
nonceHash.update(self.privateKey.decrypt(base64.b64decode(p["encrypted_nonce"]), padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()), algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), label=None)))
nonceHash = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(nonceHash.digest())
nonceHash = nonceHash.decode("utf8")
nonceHash = nonceHash.replace("/", "").replace("+", "").replace("=", "")
```

Golang code(it doesnt work)

```
base64_decoded, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(nonceProof.EncryptedNonce)
key_decrypted, _ := rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader, RAC.private_key, base64_decoded, nil)
hash := sha256.New()
hash.Write(key_decrypted)
hashDigest := hash.Sum(nil)
dst := make([]byte, base64.URLEncoding.EncodedLen(len(hashDigest)))
base64.URLEncoding.Encode(dst, hashDigest)
nonceHash := strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(strings.ReplaceAll(string(dst), "/", ""), "+", ""), "=", "")
```

Comment: I think it just some kinds of converting problems. You can look up for following link to find it. https://golang.org/doc/articles/py_gomod/